# Pausing/resuming a navigation task using Nav2 Python Simple Commander

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using the ROS2 Galactic and Nav2 stack with Python Simple Commander in a Gazebo simulation (Ubuntu 20.04).

How can I pause (and later resume) the robot's movement while navigating?

E.g. TB3 is moving along a planned path through an intersection.
I want to pause its movement using a kind of trigger, wait a few seconds, and then resume the previous navigating plan.

I checked [Simple Commander API](https://navigation.ros.org/commander_api/index.html) but I didn't find a similar command that could be used in a similar way that I would like.

I can try to work around this problem by saving the current position and the goal pose, then canceling the task with 'cancelTask()' + resuming the task with `goToPose()`, but maybe there is a better solution? Could you help me with some hints?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399573/pausing/resuming-a-navigation-task-using-nav2-python-simple-commander/) by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3064 on 2022-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/2926

I think we clearly went through this in the ticket. You could definitely write a wrapper on some functions for an application to save info like pose / goal and have that be used to send to the main navigator APIs. But that's mostly just shifting code around.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-26**:
Yes, chronologically that question was there first, only later did I fill out the feature request.

TL;DR; `cancelTask()` + `goToPose()` to the same position is the way to go.